# jsf <f:metadata> tag not inserted on template

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

This works:

`template.xhtml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8" locale="#{LanguageBean.localeLanguage}">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="token" value="#{changePasswordBean.token}"/>
        <f:viewAction action="#{changePasswordBean.checkValidToken}" />
    </f:metadata>
```

But this (based on [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html)) does not (token is always null):

`template.xhtml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8" locale="#{LanguageBean.localeLanguage}">
    <ui:insert name="metadata" />
```

`page.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>

    <html>

        <ui:define name="metadata">
            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="token" value="#{changePasswordBean.token}"/>
                <f:viewAction action="#{changePasswordBean.checkValidToken}" />
            </f:metadata>
        </ui:define>
```

Why?

Comment: it depends on the version of your jsf library and the example library

Comment: I'm currently using Mojarra JSF API Implementation 2.1.2. The JavaDoc is for 2.1.X, so it's a match, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same example working in my project code (Mojarra 2.1.29), so it must be an implementation issue. Your current JSF implementation was released more than three years ago and lots of problems have been solved since then. I recommend you to go at least with the latest 2.1.x available or to switch to 2.2.x if it's a new project. Also, you're using `f:viewAction`, which is a JSF 2.2 specific feature and simply won't properly work with your JSF implementation version.

**See also:**

- [`f:viewAction` feature](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsf22-1377252.html)

Comment: My bad. I'm actually using https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.5@12761 (I was checking an old jar which I don't know what was doing there but it wasn't being loaded and is already removed from the project). Anyway it's good to know that it really is supposed to work. I'll recheck and see if I catch what am I missing. Thanks! :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Try it with an empty template/template-client (with just parameter validation) and see if it works.